# How to build a custom report on Active Collab 5?

Tags: activecollab

There is the folder /custom/reports on Active Collab 5, but how do I build a custom report?

Anyone has a sample, I tried to understand the reports but it's too hard, no reference until now.

Comment: The answer below may not be what you expected, but that's the correct answer to your question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Purpose of that directory is for tests only. There is no way to add classes to it and have them displayed in the interface.

Use Active Collab's API to program your own reports, or import CSV files from reports section and have fun with the data in Excel.